# WiFi connection saying it's connected but no internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

Recently since switching from ethernet to wifi i have experienced issues where according to the network manager applet, I am connected to the network, but pinging any server on the both my local network and the internet results in 100% packet loss. I have experienced no issues on etherent, but i believe it may be a hardware issue as i have found [a post on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace/comments/njk751/my_wifi_randomly_disconnects_forcing_me_to_switch/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=iossmf%20*this%20post) reporting the same issue with the exact same motherboard (MSI b460m pro-vdh wifi). Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This typically occurs when the WIFI interface can talk to the router (and other devices on the lan **by MAC address**) but is not getting/using an IP configuration.

I'd check to ensure DHCP is enabled (on the computer) and that there are IP addresses available in the ip pool (on the router) and no firewall rules blocking messing with arp requests.

If that fails I'd attempt to statically assign an appropriate IP address to the WIFI interface and confirm if that works.